# Ruby Syntax for calling methods

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm farily new to the ruby language and I came across this line of code:

```
f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "bar"
```

Could somebody please explain that one to me? Because doing this:

```
f.options([:chart][:defaultSeriesType]) = "bar"
```

Gives you an error. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
    f.option([:chart][:defaultSeriesType]) = "bar"

Comment: It's because f.options it's an hash ... of course such syntax it's not legal for hash object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling with an hash.
When you have doubts like that do `f.options.inspect`, it will print out the content of the data structure. 
I'll let you understand with an example:
Based from the way you wrote, it seems that you are handling an object organized more on less in this way :

```
f.options = { chart => {defaultSeriesType => "bar"; somethingElse => "bor"}, graph => {attribute1=> "anotherString"} }
```

So you can query the object by writing: `f.options[:graph][:attribute1]` or `f.options[:chart][:somethingElse]` and so on.
I suggest you to spend one minute on http://www.tryruby.org and playing with the hash, you could also take a look here: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm#_Hashes
Sure it helps

Answer (score 3):

`f.options` should be a hash, like so

```
f.options = {:chart => {}}
```

Then the command you first wrote will work. So it is not a method call, but actually setting the value of a hash.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have questions like this, open up the console and play with the objects

```
>f.options.class
=> Hash
>f.options[:chart].class
=> Hash
```

`f.options[:chart]` is returning a Hash. So, the line `f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "bar"` is setting the value for a hash with key as 'defaultSeriesType' and value as 'bar'.

And, it's a good practice to use a symbol instead of string for keys, hence the colon at the front - `:defaultSeriesType`